# Makefile and environment variables under Cygwin

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I am trying to write some `Makefile` for a project to be compiled with `GNU make` under `Cygwin`.
Some environment variables are defined in Windows, like the path to some SDK. Say `SDKPATH C:\MySDKPath` for instance.

Within the Makefile, I am using this path to access the SDK's include directory, among other things:

`CFLAGS := -I$(SDKPATH)/include`

In the target rule:
`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@`

My problem is that after `make` expands it to `C:\MySDKPath/include` and passes it as an argument to the compiler, the argument gets expanded to `C:MySDKPath/include`, which is obviously not the intent.

I cannot really change the environment variable, since it is set by the SDK, and requiring everyone to tweak it would lead to all kinds of new problems. I could do some quick and dirty search and replace (like `MYSDKPATH := $(patsubst C:%,/cygdrive/c%,$(subst \,/,$(SDKPATH)))`), but I am wondering if there isn't a clean, established, way to handle this likely common case.

Comment: Is it just that one backslash that's getting lost, or are there several in the path?

Comment: @Beta: there are a couple of them on *my* machine, but since it's an environment variable, hence dependent on the machine, you can consider I don't know how many there is/are.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using cygwin, you can use cygpath to convert between path styles.

```
CFLAGS := -I$(shell cygpath -ua "$(SDKPATH)/include")
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an ugly kludge, but it seems to do the job in UNIX, so give it a try in Cygwin.

```
# In the makefile
SDKPATH := $(shell echo $$SDKPATH | sed 's:\\:/:g')
```

Comment: Yes that was the kind of work around I was thinking about. I haven't tried but it should work with Cygwin too. Maybe we could even use something like `sed 's@^\([A-Z]\):\@/cygdrive/\1/@1;s@\\@/@g'`. But I'm still interested in knowing what an elegant solution would be. :)